# SwiftUI: UI does not update on @Published var change

Tags: user-interface, swiftui, model, publish

So I have this model, and for simplicity I have only included one element in the posts variable. In my view I am displaying all the elements in the array and when an element is clicked, the view changes to only display information about that one post.

In this new view I have a button that indicates wether the isLiked value in the model is liked or not. I toggle between the states by using the `togglePostLike` function in the class.

If `isLiked == false` the button should have no color, and be red if it its true. The problem is that the UI doesn’t update the color / isLiked value immediately.
I also have the same functionality somewhere else in my code, but there it updates just fine.

How can I solve this?

**Model:**

```
struct Post: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var postImage: String
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var starRating: Int
    var numberOfRatings : Int
    var postRating : Double
    var postDuration : Int
    var postLanguage : String
    var publishedBy : String
    var publishedYear : Int
    var isLiked : Bool
    var author : String
}



class DataStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts = [
        Post(postImage: "post1", title: "Black Widow", description: "some description", starRating: 4, numberOfRatings: 251, postRating: 7.1, postDuration: 134, postLanguage: "English", publishedBy: "Alina", publishedYear: 2001, isLiked: false, author: "someAuthor1"),

        
    ]
    
    func togglePostLike(post: Post) {
        if let index = posts.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == post.id }) {
            posts[index].isLiked.toggle()
           
        }
    }
}
```

**View**
**UPDATED VIEW**
**UPDATED VIEW 2**

I have added a code block to show how I use dataStore and display the posts.

```
 This update is to show how the two view work together. 
struct play: View {
    @State var selectedPost : Post?
    @EnvironmentObject private var dataStore : DataStore
    
    @State var switchView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if switchView == false {
            // When iterating I call each element "post"
            Image(systemName: post.isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                .font(.system(size: 30))
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .offset(x: 100, y: 150)
                .onTapGesture {
                    if post.isLiked == true {
                        dataStore.togglePostLike(post: post)
                        let removeFromFavorite = Album(title: post.title, author: post.author, postImage: post.postImage)
                        if let index = dataStore.albums.firstIndex(of: removeFromFavorite) {
                            dataStore.albums.remove(at: index)
                        }
                        
                        
                    } else {
                        dataStore.togglePostLike(post: post)
                        let addToFavorite = Album(title: post.title, author: post.author, postImage: post.postImage)
                        dataStore.albums.append(addToFavorite)
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                }
            
            // Iterate all the posts and then give "selectedPost" the value of the clicked post
            ForEach(dataStore.posts, id:\.id) {post in
                Image("\(post.postImage)")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedPost = post
                        switchView = true
                    }
            }
            
            switchView = true
        } else {
            NewView(selectedPost: selectedPost!)
                .environmentObject(dataStore)
        }
    }
}


struct NewView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject private var dataStore : DataStore
    
    var selectedPost : Post

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text(String(selectedPost.isLiked))
            if selectedPost.isLiked {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .overlay(
                        Image(systemName: "heart")
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    )
                Text("Save")
            } else {
                Circle()
                    .strokeBorder(.black, lineWidth: 2.5)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .overlay(
                        Image(systemName: "heart")
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    )
                Text("Save")
            }
        
        }
        .onTapGesture {

            dataStore.togglePostLike(post: selectedPost)
            if selectedPost.isLiked == true {
                
                
                let removeFromFavorite = Album(title: selectedPost.title, author: selectedPost.author, postImage: selectedPost.postImage)
                if let index = dataStore.albums.firstIndex(of: removeFromFavorite) {
                    dataStore.albums.remove(at: index)
                }
                

            } else {
                
                let addToFavorite = Album(title: selectedPost.title, author: selectedPost.author, postImage: selectedPost.postImage)
                dataStore.albums.append(addToFavorite)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: 1) The view code is incomplete, we don't know how `selectedPost` is treated; 2) `@Published` variables detect changes in the value itself - so, if the array of `Post` changes - it does not read inside each single struct in the array.

Comment: @jnpdx I have made an update to my post

Comment: do you have somewhere up your views hierarachy `@StateObject var dataStore = DataStore()` declared and pass to its child views using `environmentObject(dataStore)`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine yes i do have that

Comment: there is nothing in your views `NewView` or `play` that depends on the `dataStore`.
 What is `post` in your `play` view?

Comment: I just havent included that part because its not that simple and its a lot of code. But in the Play view, just imagine a ForEach iterating dataStore.posts

Comment: So you are showing us BS code, that cannot reproduce your problem.
Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As I said before, there is nothing in your `NewView` that depends on the `dataStore`.
 So changing the `isLiked` of any post of your `dataStore` is not going to change the `NewView`.
 Note that, in `NewView`, `.onTapGesture {...}` you are **double** toggeling the `isLiked`.
 So I suggest you remove the first `dataStore.togglePostLike(post: selectedPost)`.
 Also just add `selectedPost.isLiked.toggle()` in `NewView .onTapGesture{...}`, then
 your view will **look like** it has updated the `dataStore`.

Comment: I have updated my post again, so now its should be a minimal reproducible code @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: It's still not a [mre] -- a MRE can be pasted into a blank project and run. You haven't included things like `Album` which your code depends on.

Comment: well I forgot. Either way, the problem has been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question here, but I can’t really explain the "why´s" so   feel free to add a comment with further explanation to my post.

I managed to fix the problem by changing `var selectedPost : Post` to a `@Binding`, as such: `@Binding var selectedPost : Post`.

I then also changed the `.onTapGesture` in the NewView to this:

```
.onTapGesture {

            dataStore.togglePostLike(post: selectedPost)
            if selectedPost.isLiked == true {

                // This line is new
                selectedPost.isLiked = false
                
                let removeFromFavorite = Album(title: selectedPost.title, author: selectedPost.author, postImage: selectedPost.postImage)
                if let index = dataStore.albums.firstIndex(of: removeFromFavorite) {
                    dataStore.albums.remove(at: index)
                }
                

            } else {

                // This line is new
                selectedPost.isLiked = true

                let addToFavorite = Album(title: selectedPost.title, author: selectedPost.author, postImage: selectedPost.postImage)
                dataStore.albums.append(addToFavorite)
            }

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class DataStore: ObservableObject {
 var posts = [
    Post(postImage: "post1", title: "Black Widow", description: "some description", starRating: 4, numberOfRatings: 251, postRating: 7.1, postDuration: 134, postLanguage: "English", publishedBy: "Alina", publishedYear: 2001, isLiked: false, author: "someAuthor1")
]

func togglePostLike(post: Post) {
    if let index = posts.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == post.id }) {
        posts[index].isLiked.toggle()
        objectWillChange.send() // refresh ui
    }
}
}
```

Next add onReceive SwiftUIView

```
.onReceive(dataStore.objectWillChange) { _ in 
   // update State here 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "update state here"

Comment: just add @State var refresh: bool and  replace 'update State here' with refresh.toggle() & add '
if refresh || !refresh {
 // insert your view code that need to refresh.
}
' it will update the view. If need code , let me know . I will update .
This is better way

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if it isn’t to much trouble, would you mind providing the code